# Stove and oven on same circuit?

Tags: electrical, oven, stove

Does an induction stove and an electric oven need to be on separate circuits? If they can be on one, what amperage circuit breaker do they need?

My house has a different circuit for each one, 50 amp for oven, 40 amp for stove. They are on opposite walls, and I'm redesigning my kitchen and would like to place them next to each other. So, if I could use the same circuit it would be much, much easier than having someone come out to relocate the second outlet, since I think relocating that outlet is beyond my comfort zone.

I'm looking at the amps required for a induction stove/oven combo, and they mostly say 40 amps, but when I look at just an induction stovetop by itself, it says 40 amps, and the wall oven I'm looking at says 20 amps. Little confused why it totals to much more when they are separate appliances.

Comment: This may be common knowledge, but I still feel it's worth noting based on the wording of the question and the comment that "relocating that outlet is beyond my comfort zone": The question asks about the required circuit breaker rating, but you cannot just upgrade the breaker. You will also need to make sure the wire supports the current load calculated by NEC 220.55 in the answer quoted by Kris and upgrade it if necessary if you decide to use the single circuit approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See table 220.55 in the NEC, as well as footnote 4 to that table:

> 4. Branch-Circuit Load. It shall be permissible to calculate the branch-circuit load for one range in accordance with Table 220.55. The branch-
>      circuit load for one wall-mounted oven or one counter-mounted cooking unit shall be the nameplate rating of the appliance. The branch-circuit load
>      for a counter-mounted cooking unit and not more than two wall-mounted ovens. all supplied from a single branch circuit and located in the same
>      room, shall be calculated by adding the nameplate rating of the individual appliances and treating this total as equivalent to one range.

Comment: What about manufacturers calling for a dedicated circuit? I would presume the above exception is not an option.

Comment: @Kris -- I presume that'd be a condition of listing, in which case the Art. 110 requirements that equipment be installed IAW its listing apply.

Comment: I think I'm having a difficult time interupting this section. The end sounds like it is saying to just add the nameplate rating together? I am looking at a 240V 40amp stove, and a 240V 40amp double oven. I may also do a 20amp single oven instead... undecided at this time.

Comment: @Kyle -- you apply the footnote 4 provision to add the nameplate ratings together, and *then* treat the combined load as one range when looking it up in table 220.55 to determine the demand factor you need to apply to that load.

Answer (score -2):

**Absolutely not.**

You cannot just stick two or more appliances together and call it a combo and think it will be okay.

**Edit** unless you follow the NEC 220.55 code calculations.  If the manufacturer calls for a dedicated circuit then the above exception may not apply.

As a final note, circuits should be brought up to current electrical standards if need be.

Comment: From an educational standpoint, becuase I want to learn, not trying to say you are wrong, whats different about them that makes seperate units take a total of 70 amps (40 stove, 30 oven), when a combined unit only takes 40? The stove of the combined unit is rated exactly the same kw for the burners as the seperate unit.

Comment: If I were to make a random guess I would say a computer chip performs load balancing so you can use both appliances safely.

Comment: There are special rules in the NEC for this case -- your answer isn't correct as a result.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel duly noted.